# How can I plot a dataframe with 10 columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset looks like this

```
year   china  India   United state ....
2020     30    40         50
2021     20    30         60
2022     34    20         40
....
```

I have 10 columns and more than 50 rows in this dataframe. I have to plot them in one graph to show the movement of different countries.
So I think line graph would be good for the purpose.But I don't know how should I do the visulisation.

I think I shuold change the dataframe format and then start visulisation. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot (reshape from wide to long) then plot with groups.

```r
dat <- structure(list(year = 2020:2022, China = c(30L, 20L, 34L), India = c(40L, 30L, 20L), UnitedStates = c(50L, 60L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

datlong <- reshape2::melt(dat, "year", variable.name = "country", value.name = "value")
datlong
#   year      country value
# 1 2020        China    30
# 2 2021        China    20
# 3 2022        China    34
# 4 2020        India    40
# 5 2021        India    30
# 6 2022        India    20
# 7 2020 UnitedStates    50
# 8 2021 UnitedStates    60
# 9 2022 UnitedStates    40

### or using tidyr::
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, -year, names_to = "country", values_to = "value")
```

Once reshaped, just `group=` (and optionally `color=`) lines:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(datlong, aes(year, value, color = country)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = country))
```

[image: sample ggplot2 with grouped/colored country lines]

If you have many more years, the decimal-years in the axis will likely smooth out. You can alternately control it by converting `year` to a `Date`-class and forcing the display with `scale_x_date`.

Comment: (Martin Gal secretely deletes his answer which was basically the same as r2evans... again...)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.I have another question about the distance bewteen y axis ticks. How can I change it? all the value now are displayed on the y axis

Comment: Look at `?scale_x_continuous`, namely at `breaks=`. This can accept a numeric vector (where to place them) or a function (that is given a vector of length 2, the range of the axis) that returns the numeric vector.